# Need help understanding interview qn

Tags: stream

I'm asking about the question found here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flipkart-interview-set-2-sde-2/

"(1) There is a stream of characters and at any time we need to find and remove (means set occurrence = 0) character which has maximum occurrence till now. Design data structure and algorithm for same. (I used standard Heap and Hash table setup, then was asked if we can replace lg(n) Heap operations with some efficient operation in practical scenario. I came up with doubly linked list and moving character to front on basis of its occurrences)."

I can't begin to understand the question. Any character occurring for the first time has the maximum occurrence count so far (1 > 0) so every character should get removed every time. Does anyone have a clue what the person might have actually meant?

Comment: I think "at any time" means "at an arbitrary time" rather than "after we see each character" as you interpret it.  But I also don't think this question is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

find-first-non-repeating-character-stream-characters

1. Define data structure `LinkedHashMap<charecter,count of occurances>`
2. Traverse along stream of characters if entry exists increment the
   count by one else add a new entry with count as one.
3. After traversal is over first character with count 1 will be first
   non-repeating character